# Zend_Navigator example?

Tags: zend-framework, navigator

should make a dynamic menu.
I have to do with Zend_Navigator, but I can not find good examples on the web.
Could you give me one?

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Weier O'Phinney just gave a webinar about `Zend_Navigator` this week.

The webinar is done, so you can't register, but presumably within a few days they will post a recording.  Check later at http://www.zend.com/en/company/news/event/webinar-leveraging-zend-navigator

The slides from the webinar are already online at http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/leveraging-zendnavigator